# Is growth type of leaves of foliations invariant under diffeomorphisms?

Tags: manifolds, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds, foliations, holomorphic-foliations

Let $M$ and $N$ be two complex manifolds of complex dimension $2$.

Let $\mathcal{F}_M,\mathcal{F}_N$ be a singular holomorphic one-dimensional foliation on $M,N$; respectively. Thus, the leaves of the foliations $\mathcal{F}_M,\mathcal{F}_N$ are Riemann surfaces.

Let $L_M,L_N$ be a leaf of the foliation $\mathcal{F}_M,\mathcal{F}_N$; respectively, such that $L_M,L_N$ are diffeomorphic.

Assume that the leaf $L_M$ is a hyperbolic Riemann surface (i.e., the volume of the leaf $L_M$ grows exponentially).

Under the assumptions above, is the leaf $L_N$ a hyperbolic Riemann surface as well?

Comment: Since you are not assuming compactness of $M, N$, you can simply take $M=\Delta\times \Delta$ and $N={\mathbb C}\times {\mathbb C}$, where $\Delta$ is the open unit disk in the complex plane. Compact examples exist as well, but they are more complicated.

Comment: @MoisheKohan $L_N$ may not be hyperbolic?

Comment: Complex plane is parabolic, not hyperbolic.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks